# Switch with WLAN?

Tags: networking, router, switch, wlan

I've looked quite a bit through my local electronics stores but nobody could help me there and I couldn't find what I was looking for, so I'm asking this here.

I'm looking for a "router", supporting gigabit ethernet and at least having four ports. This router should also be able to open its own WLAN network as well as act as repeater for other networks. Support for (multi-stream) 802.11ac WLAN is mandatory. Only if there's *really* nothing supporting 802.11ac 802.11n would be acceptable but it would have to have good sending power and range and support 2.4 and 5 GHz.

You'll scratch your head now and ask: Why can't a plain router be used for this? - I'm looking for a solution that is *not* a standard home router and doesn't support connecting to the internet by itself as I consider this an unnecessary feature for this device. Its use-case would be to open a new WLAN network at a physically different location from the internet access point.

Bonus points include:

- Low price (< $100)
- A webinterface for configuration purposes
- Regular updates or *really* good firmware (*really* unlikely usually)

Comment: Well it may be an unnecessary feature, but many home routers can do these tasks, and you'll probably get them cheaper than a dedicated WLAN point.

Comment: @ArtOfCode, from my experience a router with 802.11ac will hardly be available for less than $100 and usually be rather around $200+ and I *really* hope the dedicated WLAN points are alot cheaper as they don't have all those extraneous features. I think for this question to make more sense I'll drop n support.

Comment: Sure, they're expensive, but the only feature the WLAN point takes out is the Internet connectivity - which is actually a pretty trivial bit of software. There may be a couple of cheaper options around, but I wouldn't be surprised if most were pretty expensive.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Routing traffic between LAN and WAN at 1Gbit/s in software requires more CPU power than most embedded CPUs can deliver.

Comment: @kasperd The fact that the software used to get a working Internet connection via an ISP is a fairly trivial bit of software.

Comment: @ArtOfCode If it is still required to act as a router (which it might be, but that is not entirely clear from the question), then it is indeed correct that the part about configuring the connection to an ISP is just a piece of software which doesn't significantly affect the price.

Comment: A router that "doesn't support connecting to the internet by itself" is kind of like a computer that "doesn't support Ogg/Vorbis by itself".  I'll let you guess how much cheaper such a thing would be.

Comment: So you are trying to pick up one wireless network and re-broadcast it under a different name?

Comment: @Alphy13 in the years since making this post I figured out that I was essentially looking for an access point.